# Can't pan/orbit at all anymore

Tags: navigation

OS: Windows 10
Version: 2.93

Yesterday blender worked fine for modeling, and no changes have been made since, but now pan/orbit won't work. I can zoom. But can't do anything else.
What I've tried:

- pressing .
- turning off auto depth
- restarting both blender and my computer
- making sure my gaming mouse wasn't using another profile or interfering at all
- trying alt LMB
- setting orbit sensitivity to 0, also setting it back when that didn't work

none of the things suggested when I've googled worked...pan/orbit seems locked yet it's not as far as I can tell and nothing was done to lock it.

Comment: Are you sure your middle mouse button is still working?

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft Mouse or have you recently updated your mouse driver?  In either case, sometimes the system will start to capture certain mouse button events and transform them into UI events.  If's it's a MSFT mouse there's an app "Mouse and Keyboard Center" that you can use to check this.  Other mice drivers may have similar apps.

Comment: @Jakemoyo it is. works in all other programs, works well to zoom in and out even in blender,, made sure it wasn't using a different mouse profile or something set wrong, it was all fine.

Comment: @MartyFouts I'm using a logitech gaming mouse and the first thing I looked at was if it was using the wrong profile, or mmb set to something else or whatever, it wasn't. Mouse is all ok (said in reply to other comment too). It's just blender. *someone on a discord workroom I'm on also had the same issue the other day who's more experienced with me than blender, tested everything we could think of but nothing worked.

Comment: had the same problem, i just uninstalled blender and reinstalled new veersion and had no problems.